# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'plot'

Tags: python, matplotlib

Why is this matplotlib code giving me a weird exception? I'm going for two rows of plots. The top row is supposed to show true vs. pred and the bottom row is supposed to show percent error.

```
yy = func(*X)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, len(X))
for ax,_x in zip(axes,X):
    ax.plot(_x, y, 'b.')
    ax.plot(_x, yy, 'r.')

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, len(X))
for ax,_x in zip(axes,X):
    ax.plot(_x, yy/y-1, 'r.')

plt.show()
```

Traceback:

```
   File "pysr.py", line 235, in main
     ax.plot(_x, yy/y-1, 'r.')
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'plot'
```

Comment: Could you give a little more information on what `X`, `y`, and `func` are? I'm not able to reproduce the error you showed.

Just a thought, if the code you are running has a typo and is instead `for ax, _x in zip(X, axes)`, that would reproduce the error (and be a typo I could totally see myself making.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `len(X)` is >1, `axes` will be a 2D array of `AxesSubplot` instances. So when you loop over `axes`, you actually get a slice along one dimension of the `axes` array.

To overcome this, you could use `axes.flat`:

```
for ax,_x in zip(axes.flat,X):
```

Also if you are trying to plot all these on one figure, you don't need to call `plt.subplots` twice, as that will create two figures.

It may be easier to index the `axes` array like this:

```
yy = func(*X)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, len(X))

for i,_x in enumerate(X):
    axes[0, i].plot(_x, y, 'b.')
    axes[0, i].plot(_x, yy, 'r.')

    axes[1, i].plot(_x, yy/y-1, 'r.')

plt.show()
```