# AttributeError:" 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'plot'."

Tags: python, matplotlib

Was working with subplots using matplotlib but an error popped up.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,2)
for ax in axes:
    ax.plot(x,y**3)
fig
```

Comment: `for ax in axes.flat:`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'plot'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38111724/attributeerror-numpy-ndarray-object-has-no-attribute-plot)